# Unity eye to follow the player 2D

Tags: c#, 2d, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a narrative game and don't know how to accomplish something. The game is a 2D platformer so everything is build with sprites. I have a scene with trees and the trees have eyes, I want the eyes to follow the player along, but the "pupils" need to stay within the "holes" of the tree. I have made separate sprites for both the hole in the tree as well as the pupils of the eye's. I would prefer to write it in c# :).

I have also added a concept screenshot, so you can get an impression about what i'm trying to accomplish.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKSTy.jpg

Many thanks to the person who can explain to me how to accomplish this!

Answer (score 2):

Well I suppose you could use a joint to restrict the yellow pupils to stay within the holes of the eyes. [image]
Then you could use C# to calculate the relative Vector between the character and the pupil. Guide the pupil to go in the direction of the Vector, and it will be restricted by the joint to stay in the eye. The would result in the pupil always pointing in the direction of the character while staying in the eye, which is what you want.

Comment: Thanks you for you response, and the visual representation of the joint. Which kind of joint do I need to use to connect the 2 sprites if I may ask? And would such mechanic be scripted? I am not that experienced with scripting to be fair.

Comment: @You should probably use a Disance Joint 2D, and yes the pupil should be guided towards the character using scripts. If you subtract the position of the eye from the position of the character, you'll get the relative Vector between the two. Then tell the pupil to go in the Direction of that Vector (maybe using Vector2.MoveTowards), and it will move towards the character while being restricted to stay inside they eye.